# Caching the website so it doesn't reload

Tags: php, html, caching, dynamic, web

I'm having some problems with my website as it's doing a lot of SQL queries so it's pretty slow, and on click on one of the elements on the page the entire page reloads.

Here is an example:
[Example](http://www.oddsnavigator.eu/match/Soccer/Argentina%202%20Primera%20B%20Nacional/Quilmes-Guillermo%20Brown/1x2-ord-juice_a-1063764-1-1-1)

When you open the page for the first time it will take some time. Then when you click on sorting options such as "3Way", "Over/Under", "Asian Handicap" etc. it will again take the same amount of time as the page will reload together with left & right columns and the top menu.

But if you click one of those sorting options again it will be very fast as the page is cached.

I'd like the static elements (the ones which aren't changed) to not be reloaded. Automatically, if possible. If not, I'd like to be able to assign manually which elements are reloaded and which are not.

Also, when on the example URL I gave you click on "Over/Under", scroll down to 1.75, and click the little arrow next to "OVER 1.75" the page will reload and send you to top. I don't want it to go to top, but the results should be sorted without the page reloading.

If anyone can offer some assistance about these two issues I'd appreciate it, as I'm not very experienced and I only went as far as enabling far future expires headers in .htaccess.

The website is written in PHP/HTML/CSS, it's a dynamic site getting all results from a 3 GB SQL database using queries.

Thanks in advance if someone can help me out, especially as the description I gave is pretty general. I can give code if needed, but didn't know which part would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) to cache the webpages. Varnish is a HTTP proxy that sits in front of the webserver. It takes some time & knowledge to configure it, but it is a *very* good piece of software.

Alternatively, you may cache the SQL Results in memory using [shared memory](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php), [memcache](http://www.memcached.org/), or [redis](http://redis.io/).

And for the best results, you may combine both techniques!

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing caching is depends on how frequent data you want to show to user.
2. Debug you script and check whether you really need too many SQL queries. Try to reduce.
3. Avoid group by, joins, order by clause.
4. check your MySQL indexes.
5. After doing everything in MySQL start doing the caching.
6. Cached data using file, memcache even you can try mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen wrong wording.
And thus made usual so-type, who read only the title but never bother with question body, make wrong answers.

You need not caching but some AJAX/Javascript. For example, to sort a table by some column is a trivial task for the javascript. Note that this only works if whole table wits on one screen. Otherwise you will reload the page anyway.

Also, your idea of improving site loading speed is quite wrong.
First, for the *static* elements it doesn't matter if they reload or not - both will be fast.
Next, it is always a better idea to optimize your queries rather than caching entire site. 
Finally, I'd say you have to *profile* your site first, find slowest elements and then make certain steps in speed optimizing.

Comment: None of the tables fit into one screen, which means it won't work properly then. The queries are as optimized as they can be, the only other solution would be to run them all as a cron job and then export the results from XML, and read from there when the page requests it. The slowest part of the website are queries, and the fact that the page jumps to top on reload is irritating so it adds to the problem. I still don't understand though, why does the page reload all columns - even the ones which are unchanged (although they're dynamic).